# Visual Studio Team Services: Raw link to build artifacts

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines

I see several examples of Azure Resource Manager templates, referencing artifacts directly in Git Hub.

As in the following example, taken from [this](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/dsc-extension-azure-automation-pullserver/azuredeploy.json) quick start template:

```
"modulesUrl": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/raw/master/dsc-extension-azure-automation-pullserver/UpdateLCMforAAPull.zip",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "URL for the DSC configuration package. NOTE: Can be a Github url(raw) to the zip file (this is the default value)"
            }
```

As an orgnaisation, we can't use free Git Hub as code is public and as we pay for VSTS already... At the moment, we have to upload artifacts to Azure Storage Accounts using the VSTS build task *Azure Resource Group Deployment* task and reference them from there. It would be nice if we could remove this step.

So, is there a way to reference artifacts directly from a VSTS repository in a similar way to Git Hub? I assume the URI would require some form of authentication, such as a PAT token.

All I can find is [this](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell-Docs/issues/1200), but I think it is referring to packages. I don't need to create packages for ARM templates and DSC configurations.

Answer (score 0):

There is a task called [Azure Resource Group Deployment Task](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/tree/master/Tasks/AzureResourceGroupDeployment), we use this to deploy the ARM template.

[image]

According to you sample template, it's using publicly accessible http/https URLs in GitHub. Afraid this is not accessible via vsts url. In VSTS you need to follow below process (Need to use a SAS Token):

You could provide some extra parameters  using the output variables defined in the [Azure File Copy Task](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/deploy/azure-file-copy) (storageURI, storageToken). This are needed because in the template we use the `_artifactsLocation` and `_artifactsLocationSasToken` parameters to build the storage URL to the files.

More details please refer this blog: [Setting up VSTS with ARM Templates](http://blog.xebia.com/setting-up-vsts-with-arm-templates/)

Comment: Thanks. This is how we currently do it and what I am specifically asking if we can avoid. Off to user voice: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/19465411-raw-link-to-build-artefacts-in-vsts-staging-area

Comment: @woter324 Unfortunately it's not support for now.  People could not  access the VSTS https URLs  publicly.  Have voted up the uservoice , TFS PM will kindly review your suggestion.